# user toggle the font and background color

Tags: android

I have an app with 25 activities and in one activity I want to let the user choose the all app fond colour and back_ground colour and buttons colour how can I do it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".art_first_activity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="478dp"
        android:text="art1"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/group1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="500">

        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="600">

        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="700">

        </RadioButton>
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="92dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="92dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="158dp"
        android:onClick="nat"
        android:text="next" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have alot of buttons and edittext which I have to let the user change its color + back ground color in all activities

Comment: You can store the color code in shared preferences and use it in all the activities

Answer (score 0):

You can set programmatically all this things. Need to create Global variable or you can use sharedpreference for this.